# Set the default value of checkbox angular 2

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

By default the `ngModel` for `checkboxes` is set to true and false on the checking and unchecking action.

I want the value to be set to different values and not true and false. I have tried using `[ngValue]` and `[value]` but nothing worked. How to do this?

The actual scenario is:

1. I have an array of categories which can be selected.
2. There is also an option to reset all the selections made.

My markup and code:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="categories" let-i="index">
    <input id="{{item}}" type="checkbox" name="{{item}}" [(ngModel)]="categoriesSelected[i]"  [ngValue]="item">
    <label htmlFor="{{item}}">{{item}}</label>
</template>
```

What I was hoping to achieve from this was that in the `categoriesSelected` array the item names would populate and unpopulate as the checkbox is selected and unselected.

But this does not work as `ngValue` is not recognised.

I had to do the following:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="categories" let-i="index">
    <input id="{{item}}" type="checkbox" name="{{item}}" [ngModel]="categoriesSelected[i]"  (change)="checkChange(i, item, 'category')" >
    <label htmlFor="{{item}}">{{item}}</label>
</template>
```

Where in the `checkChange` function, I set the item value to the `ith` index of the `categoriesSelected` array which I later output only to the `ng-model`.

Comment: I found [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2) article I hope it helps you out.